# Does Total Recall 2070 (1999) draw from the same source material as Total Recall (1990) and Total Recall (2012)?

Tags: total-recall, total-recall-2012, total-recall-2070

I've seen pieces of the 1990 Total Recall and all of 2012's Total Recall, as well as the pilot for Total Recall 2070*. As far as I can tell, [Total Recall (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386703/) is just a remake of [Total Recall (1990)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100802/), but I'm not really sure if [Total Recall 2070](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0159920/) is related or not.

**Do these all draw from the same source material?**

*I found out during this investigation that the Miramax "movie" I have is a *tv movie* and the pilot to a 22-episode series. I have not seen the additional episodes.

Comment: I've seen Total Recall (1990) and Total Recall 2070 (1999). At first look, they appear unrelated; there are no shared characters, and events in the series don't intersect with the events of the earlier movie. The series does seem to have a more tangible connection with Blade Runner (1982) in the aesthetic and idea of synthetic people, although it seems unlikely to be part of the Blade Runner story universe.

Comment: other than the source material being written by the same author, the Minority Report and Total Recall films (all of them) are unrelated. You should edit that out because it is so wildy incorrect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it does.**

I kept digging after posting and soon found a helpful compilation of information both at Wikipedia and IMDb, showing that all of the Total Recalls in question (as well as other famous works) were adapted from the writings of Philip K. Dick. However, while Wikipedia claims that the TV adaptation Total Recall 2070 is sourced from *We Can Remember It for You Wholesale*, IMDb claims that it is sourced from *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?*; in either case, both come from the mind of Philip K. Dick.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adaptations_of_works_by_Philip_K._Dick):
[image]
[image]

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls066466708/):
[image]